# Find the number of elements of order $50$ in $\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So, my question is -- Find the number of elements of order $50$ in $G=\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$.

By using the Euler totient function I found the number of generators of the group $G$ is $40$. Let $S$ be the set of all generators of $G$. Then $2S$ will give all the elements of order $50$ but there may be some repetitions. How do I remove all the repetitions?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: An element of order $50$ will generate a cyclic group of order $50$. How many subgroups of order $50$ are there, and how many generators does each have?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ok, the number of generators of each subgroup of order $50$ is $20$. Now, I have to find the number of subgroup of order $50$. So, one such subgroup is the set of all even numbers less than $100$. If there is another such subgroup then it must contain both even and odd integer because the set of all odd integers will not form a group. So, the even and odd integer will generate $1$ which will generate the whole group. So, there is only $1$ subgroup of order $50$. Am I correct?

Comment: In fact, if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, and $d$ divides $n$, then $G$ has one and only one subgroup of order $d$ and it is cyclic. So there is one and only one subgroup of order $50$ for $\mathbb{Z}/{100}\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh ya, sorry, my bad. I already knew that but somehow missed it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

By [Chinese Remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) you may split $\mathbb{Z}_{100\mathbb{Z}} \approx \mathbb{Z}_{25\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4\mathbb{Z}}$

And this is equivalent to counting all the ordered pairs $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}_{25\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $o(a,b) = \mathrm{lcm}(o(a),o(b)) = 50$, where $o(a)$ denotes the order of $a$.

Since $50 = \mathrm{lcm}(2,25)$we can easily count all the elements of order 25 in $\mathbb{Z}_{25\mathbb{Z}}$ and of order 4 in $\mathbb{Z}_{4\mathbb{Z}}$ which respectively are $\phi(25) = 20,\phi(2) = 1$, where $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

So the number of couples of order $50$ are $20$.

Comment: This seems like too much work for this problem... though the second paragraph is useful when dealing with more general finite abelian groups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I agree. Though it's a known fact that in a cyclic finite group of order $n$ the elements of order $d \mid n$ are $\phi(d)$, i just gave an overview